# tabular multirow un-indent the first line

Tags: tables, indentation, backgrounds, multirow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [tex tabular multirow un-indent the first line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69813/tex-tabular-multirow-un-indent-the-first-line)

My question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226017/tex-tabular-multirow-un-indent-the-first-line . Can you follow?